# Adding all sums of the line

Tags: c++, string, c++17

I want to get the sum of each character of the string (ex : "1300321" would return 10)in get_line_sum function. However, it seems like my sum is not matching with what I suppose to get.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int get_line_sum(std::string x) {
    int total = 0;
    for (char &c : x) total += c;
    return total;
}
int main() {
    std::cout << get_line_sum("1300321") << std::endl;
}
```

```
c:    1   total:   0
c:    3   total:   49
c:    0   total:   100
c:    0   total:   148
c:    3   total:   196
c:    2   total:   247
c:    1   total:   297
346
```

The output is 346 instead of 10. I printed each character and total to make it easier to see what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

You are summing the character codes, not the literal digits. [See the ASCII table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html).

The ASCII code for:

- `'1'` is 49
- `'3'` is 51
- `'0'` is 48
- `'2'` is 50

Thus you get 49 + 51 + 48 + 48 + 51 + 50 + 49 which is 346.

Answer (score 2):

Traverse the string, character-by-character and convert into integer by subtracting '0' from each character.

```
int main(){

    string n = "1300321";
    int sum = 0;
    for(const auto c : n)
    {
        sum += (c - '0');
        cout<<"sum: "<<sum<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```